# Tetrix Support?

Tags: nxt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I have a lego NXT and I have the Tetrix system. Is there any support for programming the two in ROS? Is this a possibility for the future? I have been using RobotC to program it, and... well... good old C.... So, is there currently a driver/will there be one? It is a lot better than just legos...

Second question, I have the mindsensors version of the acceleration sensor... Is this one supported like the HiTechnic one? And, will it be if it isn't?

Thanks,
-Hunter A.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12797/tetrix-support?/) by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3055 on 2012-01-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Juan Antonio Breña Moral](https://answers.ros.org/users/464/juan-antonio-bre%C3%B1a-moral/) on 2012-03-19**:
Yes, in a future, we will add the support for TETRIX using LeJOS project. http://www.ros.org/wiki/nxt_lejos

**Comment by [Juan Antonio Breña Moral](https://answers.ros.org/users/464/juan-antonio-bre%C3%B1a-moral/) on 2012-03-19**:
Yes, in a future, we will add the support for TETRIX using LeJOS project.

**Comment by [Juan Antonio Breña Moral](https://answers.ros.org/users/464/juan-antonio-bre%C3%B1a-moral/) on 2012-03-19**:
Yes, in a future, we will add the support for TETRIX using LeJOS project.

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2012-04-01**:
Is there any kind of tutorial or something I can use to experiment with? Could I help with writing the drivers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The version of leJOS in SVN has the lejos.nxt.addon.tetrix package. Have a look to see if that meets your requirements. It is quite easy to build and use the latest SVN version of leJOS.

leJOS supports both the Mindsensors and HiTechnic acceleration sensors. The tutorial for nxt_lejos_proxy has just been updated.

---

Originally posted by [LawrieGriffiths](https://answers.ros.org/users/1997/lawriegriffiths/) with karma: 131 on 2012-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1